# Что делать если при движении от первого лица, камера дергается?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Делаю игру от первого лица, что-то на подобии хоррора, на движке Unity 3d. И столкнулся с проблемой, при ходьбе персонажа камера начинает дергаться. Дергается она не сильно, но всё равно очень раздражает. Реализовал скрипт поворота камеры так:

```
[Tooltip("Camera Sensetivity")]
public float sensX;
public float sensY;

public Transform orientation;

public float xRotation;
public float yRotation;

void Start()
{
    
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    Cursor.visible = false;
}


void Update()
{
    float mouseX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X") * Time.deltaTime * sensX;
    float mouseY = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y") * Time.deltaTime * sensY;

    yRotation += mouseX;
    xRotation -= mouseY;

    xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f, 90f); 

    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, yRotation, 0);
    orientation.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, yRotation, 0);


}
```

Пробовал FixedUpdate, дергать начинает ещё сильнее(

Помогите пожалуйста!!1!1!11

Comment: Камеру нужно обрабатывать не в `Update`, а в `LateUpdate`.